# Javascript textarea flatten string

Tags: javascript

```
var newString = someString.replace(/\n/, '#');
```

Works great, when i do an alert;

```
alert(newString);
```

It appears as this:

```
"Firstline
#Secondline
#ThirdLine"
```

I wish for it to display:

```
"Firstline#SecondLine#Thirdline"
```

This is screwing up my other coding!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some OS have `\r\n` for newlines. So, add an optional carriage return character to the RegExp. Also, add a [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) flag to your RegExp if you want to replace all occurrences:

```
var newString = someString.replace(/\r?\n/g, '#');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using...

```
var newString = someString.replace(/\n\r?/g, '#'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
someString.replace(/[\r\n]+/, '#');
```

Comment: Consecutive newlines will be replaced by a single `#`.

Comment: Indeed, i'd assumed this was the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to prepend `#` to each line you might want this:

```
someString.replace(/^/gm, "#")
```

> #Firstline
>       #Secondline
>       #ThirdLine

Answer (score 0):

I would recommmend the following

```
function flatString(s) {
    // remove line separators (windows and linux) and trim multiple spaces
    s = s.replace(/\r\n/g, ' ')
        .replace(/\r/g, ' ')
        .replace(/\n/g, ' ')
        .replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ')
        .trim();

    return s;
}
```

You first delete the Windows line ends (\r\n are always together), then you remove the single characters (for linux line ends).

At this point, you flatted the string. However, depending on how many newline characters you had, you may end up with many spaces. So we try to convert all n-spaces to single spaces, and lastly do a trim so we get the shortest string as possible.

NOTE: this can be further optimized to try to run the most regex possibilities in a single execution, but it makes the cut at least.